# Sitecore - Custom field, add unique value on create

Tags: c#, vb.net, sitecore, sitecore7

I want to create a field that generates a running number. This number will be automatically generated everytime I create a new item and has to be unique.

Any examples of how this could be implemented? I don't want to use the Sitecore item ID for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a custom token and just use your field. I think this is going to be the cleanest solution for your problem. You can add your custom algorithm to guarantee that the IDs are unique or you can just use `Guid.NewGuid()`. You can check how to create custom tokens in this [blog post](http://nsgocev.wordpress.com/2014/08/03/sitecore-custom-tokens/).

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I came up with a solution inspired by the nsgocev blogpost. Our IDs needed to be stored somewhere, so I created an item inside the /sitecore/content/ that stores the last ID as a string. Set the start as "AA000000". Our Ids has a prefix of "AA" and 6 digits.

This is the logic that counts:

```
Namespace Tokens

Public Class GeneratedArticleId
    Inherits ExpandInitialFieldValueProcessor

    Public Overrides Sub Process(ByVal args As ExpandInitialFieldValueArgs)
        If args.SourceField.Value.Contains("$articleid") Then
            Dim database = Sitecore.Client.ContentDatabase
            Dim counter = database.GetItem(New ID("Our Item"))

            If counter Is Nothing Then
                args.Result = ""
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Dim idfield = AppendToIdValue(counter("ID"))

            Using New SecurityDisabler()
                counter.Editing.BeginEdit()
                counter.Fields("ID").Value = idfield
                counter.Editing.EndEdit()
            End Using

            If args.TargetItem IsNot Nothing Then
                args.Result = args.Result.Replace("$articleid", idfield)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    'Extracts the digits and adds one

    Private Shared Function AppendToIdValue(ByVal id As String)
        Dim letterprefix = Left(id, 2)
        Dim integervalue = CInt(id.Replace(letterprefix, ""))
        integervalue += 1
        Return letterprefix & integervalue.ToString("000000")
    End Function
End Class
End Namespace
```

We also need to add our class to the web config file. Patch given class in:

```
  <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
      <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
          <expandInitialFieldValue help="Processors should derive from Sitecore.Pipelines.ExpandInitialFieldValue.ExpandInitialFieldValueProcessor">
            <processor patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.ExpandInitialFieldValue.ReplaceVariables, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="OurLibrary.Tokens.GeneratedArticleId, OurLibrary"/>
          </expandInitialFieldValue>
        </pipelines>
      </sitecore>
  </configuration>
```

Now when we create a new item with token "$articleid", the ID is AA000001. The next one will be AA000002 and so on.

Thank you @nsgocev for resource and answer.