# Sitecore multisites website URL routing

Tags: sitecore

I am working on sitecore multisites . I have multiple websites ex test1, test2, test3, test4. All are configured in webconfig. Means test1, test2 ,test3 and so on . So URL //test1  will always point to there local home folder which will be inside of test1/home.

But as per my requirement i have one global folder which are separate from all websites but pages inside of this will be common for all websites.

Ex:

sitecore/Root/Global/Category/A

sitecore/Root/test1

sitecore/Root/test2

sitecore/Root/test3

Now i am not able to get page A if i am in  //test1 , and want to access page A and URL should be to //test1/Category/A.

Please help.

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for [Item Clones](http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/10/Sitecore-CMS-6-4-Cloning.aspx)

Comment: Please suggest how can i do this .

Answer (score 1):

*I'm not usually a fan of re-posting an exact answer that I posted previously, especially when I posted the original barely over a week ago, but the following is from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26143140/1506793).*

Every page that is managed in Sitecore is a Sitecore Item. As such, you should be able to just navigate to the name of the player item. If you were trying to say in your post that category items are stored in globals and not as pages, then you are left with the following options:

1. Query String: `test1/Category?categoryId={ID of Category}`

   - If this is the route that you choose to take then I would suggest using the category item's Sitecore ID for the value of the query string parameter.
   - If you have other IDs then put the specified ID there, however it would be easiest with Sitecore IDs
   - What you would then do is get the item with the ID specified in the query string parameter (or get the item with the category ID specified in the query string parameter, depending on which route you take) and display the data for that category on the page

     - `Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Request.QueryString["categoryId"])`
     - `categoryItems.FirstOrDefault(categoryItem => categoryItem["Category ID"] == Request.QueryString["categoryId"])`

       - Note that this assumes that the Category ID is a field, not the Sitecore ID
       - If it is the Sitecore ID then change the lambda to use `categoryItem.ID == new ID(Request.QueryString["categoryId"]`
     - Regardless of which one you use, I suggest adding null checks to the QueryString getter
2. Sublayout Parameters

   - If you use this method, the query string will not change and people will not be able to get to the page from the direct URL
   - The process is the same as for query strings, except that you are using Sublayout parameters instead
   - Note that you must set these in a parent sublayout or in Sitecore (which means that you have a separate page for each player - i.e. this would be a bad solution)
3. Virtual Items

   - This is really what I think you are looking for
   - This can be a lot of work if you do it from scratch, or you can use [the Wildcard Module](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/getting-to-know-sitecore/posts/2011/09/wildcards-and-data-driven-urls.aspx)
   - If you do it from scratch, you will need a custom pipeline and/or processor for handling the requests

Comment: Thanks for solution . But this is not actually i am looking for . I  am looking for i can get item URL and then customize it based on requirement

Comment: Actually, it is exactly what you are looking for. That is what the Wildcard Module and Virtual Items do. You create a fake URLs that actually point to the items you configure them to point to instead of pointing to real items.

Answer (score 1):

If the [Wildcard Module](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Wildcard_module.aspx) isn't going to work, and if this is the case for all sites in your Sitecroe instance, you could write a custom item resolver and insert it in the httpBeginRequest pipeline right after the built in item resolver.

This is sort of from memory, but should get you started:

```cs
namespace Example
{
    public class CategoryItemRewsolver : Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
        {
            if (Sitecore.Context.Item != null) return; // Item has already been resolved

            if (args.Context.Request.Path.StartsWith("Category"))
            {
                Sitecore.Context.Item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("sitecore/Root/Global" + args.Context.Request.Path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll obviously want to replace paths with your own (And possibly allow them to be configured through the .config file).

Then patch this into the pipeline:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <httpRequestBegin>
                <processor patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="Example.CategoryItemResolver,Example" />
            </httpRequestBegin>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```